# Select an option without changing the dropdown's value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a possibility to select an *option* while the dropdown is open, without having it to close and change the *select*'s value? Like only higlighting it, to be chosen when tabbing out.

Visibly the same as navigating through the *option*s with the arrow-keys while having the *select* opened.

jQuery is welcome :)

Workarounds welcome :p

- To be clear:

```html
<select>
    <option>Option 1 (A)</option>
    <option>Option 2 (B)</option>
    <option>Option 3 (C)</option>
</select>
```

I need to select the specific option by pressing a char that's in the brackets.

Comment: I suspect you'll need to code a custom component to do this - it sounds like a confusing user experience though.

Comment: It's about catching key 'A' while selecting option 'foo (A)' but keep the select opened if it was opened manually - like what the browser does when pressing 'f'

Comment: Please look at the codesample, that should point out my requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most browsers, this is the default behavior when the letter is at the beginning of the label instead of the end, so you might try that.

Otherwise, you might add a class to the option that should be "highlighted", then use CSS to style that class however you want. You would want to remove that class from all options on mouse move or keydown so the dual highlighting (native plus your CSS) isn't too confusing. I don't know if you can use CSS to remove the native highlighting altogether, but that would be nice. Then it's just a matter of setting the value correctly when the select element loses focus, which is trivial.